# java regex: match word after another with at least one digit

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have two Strings:

```
    String s1 = "The demo 505/rj is bad";   
    String s2 = " demo zero 4";
```

`String val="demo"`, `String g = s1` or `s2`, and regex pattern:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=" + val +")\\s*\\b(?=\\D*\\d)\\S+\\b");
Matcher m = p.matcher(g);
if (m.find()) {
        String s = g.substring(m.start(), m.end());
        System.out.println(s);
}
```

Two possible cases:

- If `g = s1`, `s = 505/rj` - means for me that pattern works fine
- If `g = s2`, `s = zero` - is bad - because word "zero" not contains at least one digit

Note: besides alphanumeric,the word also can contains special characters

How can I modify this pattern to solve problem for both cases 1 and 2?

Comment: what do you mean by work for both? What is your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace the `\D` with `\S` in your regex pattern, because `\D` matches any char other than a digit (so, it matches a space!), and checks farther than the non-whitespace chunk after the current word.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=" + val +")\\s*\\b(?=\\S*\\d)\\S+\\b");
                                                      ^^^^
```

See [this Java demo](https://ideone.com/fwCD5t)

You can also get the whole match accessing it via `matcher.group(0)`, there is no need to get a substring from `g` using `m.start()`/`m.end()`.

And here is an enhancement: you can get rid of the lookbehind (they are costly) and use a capturing group:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(val + "\\s*\\b(?=\\S*\\d)(\\S+)\\b");
                            ^^^                      ^^^^^^
//...
String s = m.group(1);
```

See [this updated demo](https://ideone.com/sPMpXu)

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the lookbehind and lookahead, use lazy matching and a capturing group to simplify this regex:

```
val + "\\s+(\\S*?\\d+\\S*?)\\s+"
```